# Расчитать масштаб яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

На карте есть основная точка (центр карты) и дополнительные точки к которым рисуется линии.
Как рассчитать масштаб карты зная координаты центра карты и координаты точки (точка на карты не отрисована еще, масштаб нужно подогнать до отрисовки второй точки)

Answer (score 0):

1)   нужно вычислить максимальное расстояние между центром и всеми точками,  здесь https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html 
    есть формула рассчета расстояния между двумя точками на карте  и пример для js

2) для яндекс карты уровень зума в зависимости от вычисленного макс расстояния примерно следующий (расстояние в км):

```
24576 - 12288 -- 1 (если расстояние от 12288 до 24576 км, то зум 1)
12288 - 6144 -- 2
6144 - 3072 -- 3
3072 - 1536 -- 4
1536 - 768 -- 5
768 - 384 -- 6
384 - 192 -- 7
192 - 96 -- 8
96 - 48 -- 9
48 - 24 -- 10
24 - 11 -- 11
11 - 4.8 -- 12
4.8 - 3.2 -- 13
3.2 - 1.6 -- 14
1.6 - 0.8 -- 15
0.8 - 0.3 -- 16
0.3 -  0 -- 17
```

Comment: Не совсем правильная карта зума, он ведь зависит от размера размера карты и т.д. также точка может находится как по диагонали (в углу карты) так и перпендикулярно (по середины меньшей стороны края карты) соответственно там разные расстояния